# Copy part of a mesh with an edgeloop as starting point

Tags: mesh, snapping

[image]

the red circle is the exact same size as the edge loops of the three holes... 
how can i get a copy of the selected mesh matching rotation and position of the holes...? i tried to snap with all different settings in edit and object mode and had a lot more other attemps but nothing worked out yet

Comment: Are the openings really the same? It might be much easier to snap the copied selection above the hole and use Bridge Edge Loops to connect it. Then dissolve any unnecessary loops

Comment: maybe it looks a bit wrong because of rotation but they are identical, i thought maybe there would be a way by selecting the edge loops of the openings and than paste in the copied mesh